# Imagick distort bug: trailing line

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I use Imagick to compose edible paper designs containing images and/or text. 
One of the features users can access when it comes to adding text, besides font, size or color, is curvature (curved text), for which I use the *distortImage* method, like so:

```
$image->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_ARC, [ -$angle ], true);
```

The problem with this is that from time to time, a trailing, somewhat faded line appears in generated designs, at the left of the text, like in the image bellow:

[image]

I'm not sure why this happens, but it's not random. I.e. it only appears for certain letters, but that's also dependent on the font used. In other others, distorting text that starts with *h* does not create a trailing line with only some combinations of font/size. But if it does, it will always appear for that combination, so it's not an on/off thing.

Any ideas as to what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Can't test it right now, but can you try adding a white/transparent border to all image before distorting? Maybe it's a border/interpolation issue

Comment: @Sga: Fantastic idea! That solved the problem. :)